Our guests are expected to ________by 4 o'clock this afternoon

be arrived
have arrived
have been arrived
will arrive

What is the right answer?

Please don't just post homework questions.  Please explain what you don't understand


Our guests are expected to arrive by 4 o'clock this afternoon.

This is because "to arrive" is an infinitive.  This is standard for "expected to"

But the simple infinitive isn't one of the choices listed by OP. There is a subtle difference, in that ...expected to have arrived implies the "latest expected arrival time" is of greater significance than is suggested by the plain infinitive. So if both were offered as answer choices, it would be a bad test (because both are okay; they just have slightly different meanings).

"to arrive" is not listed among the options.

Nevertheless, it is the correct answer.

@Mary: If the infinitive was offered as a choice, it would be a "correct answer", as explained by my previous comment. But (as also explained), if both infinitive and present perfect were offered as choices, it would be a bad test.

This isn't a test.  It's a question on the Stack Exchange

Of the offered options, "to have arrived" is the only possible answer.
It has a different sense from "expected to arrive by 4 o'clock". It suggests the guests will have arrived at some time before four, but no later than four.

Because it's by rather than at 4 o'clock, the basic / literal meaning of expected to arrive and ...to have arrived is the same anyway. The only difference I see is the Perfect version ascribes greater significance to the fact that they aren't expected to arrive later than 4 o'clock.

It's infinitesimals anyhow, but one might see  "by 4 o'clock" as allowing arrival at four, but having arrived by four doesn't allow that.

That tiny difference can only exist if we allow that the act of arriving takes time. Which I suppose in practice would normally  be true. It is odd that the test doesn't include the simple infinitive as a choice, though, since I think in the vast majority of cases, that's what people would use, irrespective of that tiny difference in exact timing, and the element of "emphasis / urgency" I believe is implied by Present Perfect.

Maybe the infinitive was earlier in the course.

Nah. It's a test set by "Anglophonic incompetents". Google "Our guests are expected to" "by 4 o'clock this afternoon" for a pointer to the origin!
